# Can't find Denoiser in 2.79b

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I just installed Blender 2.79b, but I can't find Denoiser. What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: It's only in Cycles render, you are in Blender render currently.

Comment: @FFeller Found it! Thanks!